# Spark: How to merge json objects into array

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark

I have the following JSON Array in on of the columns of Dataframe in Spark (2.4)

```
[{"quoteID":"12411736"},{"quoteID":"12438257"},{"quoteID":"12438288"},{"quoteID":"12438296"},{"quoteID":"12438299"}]
```

I am trying to merge as

```
{"quoteIDs":["12411736","12438257","12438288","12438296","12438299"]}
```

Require help on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **`from_json`** to read your column data as `array<struct>` then by exploding we can flatten the data.

- finally do `groupBy + collect_list` to create an array and use **`to_json`** to create json required.

**`Example:`**

```
val df=Seq(("a","""[{"quoteID":"123"},{"quoteID":"456"}]""")).toDF("i","j")

df.show(false)

//+---+-------------------------------------+
//|i  |j                                    |
//+---+-------------------------------------+
//|a  |[{"quoteID":"123"},{"quoteID":"456"}]|
//+---+-------------------------------------+

val sch=ArrayType(new StructType().add("quoteID",StringType))

val drop_cols=Seq("tmp1","tmp2","j")

//if you need as column in the dataframe
df.withColumn("tmp1",from_json(col("j"),sch)).
withColumn("tmp2",explode(col("tmp1"))).
selectExpr("*","tmp2.*").
groupBy("i").
agg(collect_list("quoteID").alias("quoteIDS")).
withColumn("quoteIDS",to_json(struct(col("quoteIDS")))).
drop(drop_cols:_*).
show(false)

//+---+--------------------------+
//|i  |quoteIDS                  |
//+---+--------------------------+
//|a  |{"quoteIDS":["123","456"]}|
//+---+--------------------------+

//if you need as json string
val df1=df.withColumn("tmp1",from_json(col("j"),sch)).
withColumn("tmp2",explode(col("tmp1"))).
selectExpr("*","tmp2.*").
groupBy("i").
agg(collect_list("quoteID").alias("quoteIDS"))

//toJSON (or) write as json file
 df1.toJSON.first
//String = {"i":"a","quoteIDS":["123","456"]}
```